# laravel 5.1 user registration database insertion

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

First i have a `UserController` controller to authenticate new users and register them. I have two methods `index` for login and `create` for registering a new user. But the `Create` method doesn't work, No error occurs but the data is not going to database table.

Second the `signup` form reload to its self after submission. `signup` form have no action.

The `userController` code :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher;
use Illuminate\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $cred = Input::only('email','password');
        var_dump($cred);
        if(Auth::attempt($cred)){
          return Redirect::intended('index');
        }else{
          $error = "Username or password is incorrect.";
          return Redirect::to('/signup');
        }
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $user = new \App\User;
        $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->username = Input::get('username');
        $user->email  =   Input::get('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->designation = Input::get('profile_pic');
        $user->save();
        return view('index');
    }
```

Routes :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('index', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('login');
});
Route::post('login', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/signup', function(){
    return view('signup');
});
Route::post('/signup', ['uses' => 'UserController@create']);
```

`User` Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname','username','email', 'password','photo'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

Comment: can u share your model(User)?

Comment: Have you set the mass-assignable fields on the model? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: There is no mass-assignment going on

Comment: You should turn on errors. You are using the `Input` facade but referencing it with a lowercase *i*. That could be it.

Comment: Question updated. @JoachimMartinsen

Comment: Also, you are setting `$user->username` 3 times. Which is fine and will work. But doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have updated both the question and the code, Still data is not going to the database. @JoachimMartinsen

Comment: Yeah, we need to see some errors. Delete `storage/logs/laravel.log` (or move it elsewhere if you need it). Run the code once, and paste the errors here.

Comment: I have deleted `storage/logs/laravel.log`and then run the code, but the file is not coming back @JoachimMartinsen

Comment: Make sure the user running the web server have proper write permissions to the storage folder.

Comment: i am using ubuntu linux. @JoachimMartinsen

Comment: If this is a local web server then you're probably fine with running `chmod -R 777 storage/`. This should not be done on a production server though. File permissions and security is another chapter.

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen bro still not creating the log file :(
I am tired of the this error please help

Comment: Figure out the log issue. Without knowing what errors you are getting it's hard to know.

Comment: I see that you are setting `$user->designation`. Is that right, or should it be `$user->photo`?

Comment: ok stay connected i am pasting the log errors in a couple of minutes

Comment: @khan the traits you are using effecting your code, either you use them as part of Laravel authentication system or not. let me know if you still looking for a solution

Comment: Maybe add some validation so you know where your data’s failing…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the get method on the Input facade has been removed and now uses the input method instead.

Since you're using Laravel, one of the cool features is Eloquent and your models. You can write your code like this and it's much more clean...

```
use App\User;

public function create(Request $request) {
   $input = $request->only('firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'profile_pic');
   return User::create($input);
}
```

In your case, you're building up the model instance and persists it to the database later on. That's only useful if you want to do other checks without persisting the model to the database. If you insist to do it your way, you need to call the input method on the facade, like this:

```
$user->firstname = Input::input('firstname');
```

I hope that helps! :D